# PHP showing errors despite php.ini forbid it

Tags: php, error-reporting

we have forbidden to show errors on our server. But I'd need to show the errors in my script despite it.

I tried this:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", "on");
    echo "chyba"
    echo "nazdárek";
?>
```

But it is not useful. Thank you for your help.

Comment: 1. Your opening tag is missing a `<` at the start 2. What's your question?

Comment: What does that mean, it is not useful?

Comment: It is not functional. I can't see errors

Comment: @Rizier123 Only mistake made by copying my script to this page. Corrected.

Comment: See this would work http://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/2334975

Answer (score 1):

Your call to [`error_reporting()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) doesn't do anything because it does not run.

There is a missing `;` after the first `echo`. I know you know about it, you made the mistake on purpose, to show that `error_reporting()` doesn't do what you expect it to do.

**It doesn't work this way.** The missing semicolumn is a syntax error. The script does not compile, so it does not run. Your call to `error_reporting()` is not executed and that means the value of the [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) configuration directive is the one that decides what errors are reported.

You have to fix the syntax errors first, make the script compile & run, and **only after that** try to trigger a runtime error and see if it is reported back to you. I bet it is.

A runtime error or warning is easy to generate. Try a division by zero, for example.

Comment: I know what are you meaning, but I needed to show for example: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO), expecting ',' or ';' in... Because I don't have access to php.ini on our server and need to show my syntax mistakes.

Comment: You don't need to put the files on the live server to check them for syntax errors. Install PHP on your development computer and use [`php -l`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php) to check the script for errors.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to produce there is a *syntax error*. This won't work within the same file that you're setting error reporting. The file first needs to be parsed in its entirety. If there's a syntax error in the file, then none of its code will be executed, so no error reporting will be switched on.

Comment: So I can't do that it wrotes me for example this one? Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO), expecting ',' or ';' in

Comment: Not within the same file. If you put your `error_reporting` instructions in one file and then `include` another file with syntax errors, it'll work.

Comment: What a pity. I have no access to php.ini to turn mistakes on, so I thought to do it in my script. Something like ignore php.ini and show me my errors.

Comment: You *may* be able to override PHP settings in an .htaccess file with `php_flag` directives. Google around a bit.

Comment: But honestly, syntax errors are things you should be catching in your local editor/IDE before they even touch your server. If you're uploading files which don't even compile there's something wrong with your workflow that you should fix.

Comment: Can you suggest me something? I use Notepad++ and that has only html  highlight correction, but no correction for php syntax errors.

Comment: And you're also not even running your files locally? Get a local web server installed, maybe a virtual machine even. Personally I'm a fan of PhpStorm, if you're willing to spend some cash.